# Optimizing Memory Management for Frequent Tree Updates in C++: Memory Pool vs. Native new/delete Operations

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management

I'm currently dealing with a tree structure implemented using Node objects, and my application requires frequent insertions and removals within this tree. While the number of nodes in the tree doesn't significantly increase over time, I'm concerned about the potential heap operation overhead when using the traditional C++ new/delete operations.

I'm considering a more memory-efficient approach using a memory pool. Specifically, I'm thinking of maintaining a static vector of Node objects and utilizing overloaded new/delete operators to manage elements within this vector. Additionally, I would maintain another static vector to keep track of free address slots, ensuring sequential storage on the heap.

My question is whether this memory pool approach is a smart or suboptimal solution for my specific use case? I want to strike the right balance between memory efficiency and performance. Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, I'd test to find out whether the problem you're trying to solve is really significant. If you find it really is, I'd look up one of the (many) existing allocators for such purposes (going all the way back to the [Loki](https://github.com/snaewe/loki-lib) small object allocator). To answer your direct question: it certainly can be smart. Your first try will probably be suboptimal as well, but even if it's suboptimal, it can still be an improvement over using the normal free store directly.

Comment: @JerryCoffin do you assume by default C++ isn’t very smart for allocating objects of same types many time?

Comment: I don't assume it *is* by default, but experience shows that in some cases it *can* be.

Comment: The idea with static vector looks strange because for default its implementation the data will most likely be placed in the heap.

Comment: @triclosan indeed, but once the vector chunk is allocated, no more malloc/free are needed, deleted elements are reused in place preventing any memory fragmentation.

Comment: I probably should add: it doesn't seem like I've had to deal with problems along this line recently as much as I did, say, 15 to 20 years ago. Probably partly better default heap allocators, but also probably at least some just because memory is a lot more plentiful so less efficient usage isn't as big of a problem as it used to be.

Comment: @nowox, I don't get the difference between stack and static vectors at that point.

Comment: If your tree size (including spare nodes for copying) is bounded, you can get away with just a vector of nodes and a free-list. You must size the vector up-front. If not, reallocations will invalidate your pointers. Use `std::deque` to get around that if you want to grow memory dynamically. At this point, what you have is an _object pool_. Your allocator dishes out an available object from the pool or expands the pool. You can implement a rough-and-ready version of this quite quickly and then benchmark it to determine if it matters. Asking whether to try this, instead of just trying, is weird.

Comment: Modern global allocator can be very efficient. Unless you have some specificities you can use to make malloc/free faster, it tends to be a wast of time (and make the code less maintainable and short). A lot of modern allocators uses buckets for small objects. There is no memory fragmentation with bucket allocator by design, only a memory overhead. If your allocations have a power of two size, then the overhead should be small.

Comment: You can write a faster allocator if you know that there is no multiple threads operating on the same data structure (adding/removing nodes) since there is no need for atomics or locks. There is one benefit of memory pool : memory diffusion. Indeed, objets are closer in memory so it can improve locality. Still implementing an allocator only for that does not worth it. Implementing a fast allocator competitive with the state-of-the-art is *very* hard. By the way, note that the fastest allocators tends to use more memory (there is no free lunch).